# Replace Form1.Panel1 with Form2.Panel1

Tags: vb.net, replace, controls

I'm trying to find a way to replace one panel form `Form1` with the panel created in `Form2`, while replacing to have same size and same location.

Exammple:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Me.Panel1.Hide()
    Form2.Panel1.Show()
    Form2.Panel1.Location = Me.Panel1.Location
    Form2.Panel1.BringToFront()
End Sub
```

It want to be something like tabcontrol, but I prefer to use label because tabcontrol is so limited to do what I want to do.

Comment: so what is your problem? you cannot see `Form1.Panel1` on `Form2`? is it?

Comment: Conversely. From Form2 in Form1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you cannot see "**the controls in `Form2`**" (`Panel1` in this case) on the `Form1`, because the controls in `Form2` are belong to `Form2`. 
Thus, if you want to see `Form2.Panel1` on `Form1`, you need to add `Form2.Panel1` to `Form1.Controls`.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.Controls.Add(Form2.Panel1)
    Form2.Panel1.Hide()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Me.Panel1.Hide()
    Form2.Panel1.Show()
    Form2.Panel1.Location = Me.Panel1.Location
    Form2.Panel1.Size = Me.Panel1.Size 'to be the same size
End Sub
```

Comment: Oh my God, thank you so much! I also found a solution, but your code is more beautiful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean to type Form2?

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles     Button1.Click
    Me.Panel1.Hide()
    Form2.Panel1.Show()
    Form2.Panel1.Location = Me.Panel1.Location
    Form2.Panel1.BringToFront()
End Sub
```

You might not need the `BringToFront` statement either.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to edit since is just a example in my request. And this code don't work. Is just hide the panel from main form, but I can't see the panel from form2.

Comment: Let me try with one borderless form instead of panel, maybe it should work. Edit: It doesn't work. It show the form2 but in a random location than panel from main form.

Comment: Oh, yes. This would show the panel on Form2. Which is probably already visible on that form.

Comment: Perhaps you can just use:  `Me.Panel1 = Form2.Panel1` as your click handler code?

Comment: It needs to be added to Form1 Controls collection.`Controls.Add(Form2.Panel1)` It will appear in the same position on Form1 as it does on Form2. I tried this with a label, not sure how it would work with a panel.

Comment: Yes, now I know! Thank you so much for helping me. Look at Tun Zarni Kyaw answer to see the final code. Thank you again for everything!